# jQuery: Validation, best way to do this?

Tags: jquery

I have a simple form with basic info e.g.

```
<label>*Name:</label> [inputbox]
<label>*email:</label> [inputbox]
<label>Company:</label> [inputbox]
<label>Phone:</label> [inputbox]

[submit]
```

I just want simple validation that turns the input box border red and the text e.g. "*name" red.... I think many validation scripts might be a bit heavy for this simple functionality...

Can anyone reocomend something simple to achieve validation as per above please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Description

One lightweight way ist to use jQuery `Validation`

#### Sample

**Html**

```
<label for="Company">Company:</label> 
<input id="Company" type="Text" name="Company"/>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#YourFormId").validate({
    rules: {
        Company: "required",
    },
    messages: {
        Company: "Please enter your Company",
    }
});
```

#### More Information

- [jQuery plugin: Validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)
- [jQuery - Plugins/Validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)

Answer (score 1):

This plugin could help you out :

[Site](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

[Demo](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/)

Comment: This pops up with the tex "This field is required." - I don't need that :(